# После оператора не вызывается деструктор

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, память

```
class Test2 {
private:
    unsigned char* arr;
    size_t size;
public:
    ~Test2() {
        free(this->arr);
        this->size = 0;
    }
    Test2(size_t size) {
        this->size = size;
        this->arr = (unsigned char*)calloc(size, sizeof(this->arr));
    }
    Test2(Test2 const& copy) : size(copy.size), arr(new unsigned char[copy.size]){
        memcpy(this->arr, copy.arr, copy.size);
    }
    Test2(Test2&& x) noexcept {
        free(this->arr);
        this->size = x.size;
        this->arr = x.arr;
    }
    void Resize(size_t newsize) {
        this->arr = (unsigned char*)realloc(this->arr, newsize);
        for (size_t i = this->size; i < newsize; i++) {
            this->arr[i] = 0;
        }
        this->size = newsize;
    }
    void Set(size_t index, unsigned char value) {
        if (index < size) {
            this->arr[index] = value;
        }
        else {
            throw new exception("Out of bounds of an array");
        }
    }
    Test2& operator<<(size_t N) {
        Test2* c = new Test2(this->size + N);
        for (size_t i = N; i < this->size + N; i++) {
            c->Set(i, this->arr[i - N]);
        }
        return *c;
    }
    Test2& operator=(const Test2& rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            free(this->arr);
            memcpy(this->arr, rhs.arr, rhs.size);
            this->size = rhs.size;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Test2& operator=(Test2&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            free(this->arr);
            this->arr = rhs.arr;
            this->size = rhs.size;
            rhs.arr = nullptr;
            rhs.size = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test2 a(3); //1, 0, 1
    a.Set(0, 1);
    a.Set(2, 1);

    //Test2 b = a << 3;

    Test2 b(1);
    b = a << 3;
}
```

Выполняется оператор << потом оператор присваивания копированием, а временная переменная c так и не удаляется. Еще и в конце кода вызываются деструкторы a и b и в b происходит ошибка нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу. Если сделать как в закомментированной части кода, то этой ошибки нет и вызывается оператор копирования, но временная переменная так же не очищается. Я проверял содержимое этой переменной после выполнения кода и убедился что там все то же что и в b, только адреса другие. Как правильно сделать класс, чтобы временная переменная c очищалась и не происходило ошибок в деструкторе b? Если временную переменную делать в стеке, то он вызовет деструктор раньше конструктора копирования и в итоге скопируется мусор. Конструктор и оператор перемещения вообще не вызываются...

Answer (score 3):

Даже непонятно, какой вариант разбирать - старый или новый... Наверное, возьмемся за новый.

Сразу общее: вы нигде не проверяете результат выделения/перераспределения памяти. И вообще используете в C++ работу с памятью в стиле C...

А дальше - см. комментарии к коду.

```
class Test2 {
private:
    unsigned char* arr;
    size_t size;
public:
    ~Test2() {
        free(this->arr);
        this->size = 0;    // Просто не имеет смысла
    }
    Test2(size_t size) {
        this->size = size;

        // this->arr = (unsigned char*)calloc(size, sizeof(this->arr));
        // Зачем здесь память для size УКАЗАТЕЛЕЙ? логичнее уж calloc(size, sizeof(*this->arr));
        // Хотя самое логичное - new unsigned char [size]. C++ все же...
        this->arr = (unsigned char*)calloc(size, sizeof(*this->arr));

    }
    Test2(Test2 const& copy) : size(copy.size),
        // arr(new unsigned char[copy.size])
        // Ай-я-яй!!! Запрещено смешивать два варианта! Или С'шный, или С++
        arr((unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*copy.size))
    {
        memcpy(this->arr, copy.arr, copy.size);
    }

    Test2(Test2&& x) noexcept {
        this->size = x.size;
        this->arr = x.arr;
        x.arr = nullptr;
        x.size = 0;
    }

    void Resize(size_t newsize) {
        this->arr = (unsigned char*)realloc(this->arr, newsize);
        // А вы уверены, что увеличение будет только в большую сторону?...
        for (size_t i = this->size; i < newsize; i++) {
            this->arr[i] = 0;
        }
        this->size = newsize;
    }

    void Set(size_t index, unsigned char value) {
        if (index < size) {
            this->arr[index] = value;
        }
        else {
            throw new exception("Out of bounds of an array");
        }
    }

    Test2 operator<<(size_t N) {
        // Логику - что вы хотите получить - что-то не понимаю...
        // Но криминала не вижу.
        Test2 c(this->size + N);

        for (size_t i = N; i < this->size + N; i++) {
            c.Set(i, this->arr[i - N]);
        }
        return c;
    }

    Test2& operator=(const Test2& rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            free(this->arr);

            // И КУДА вы копируете?! В освобожденную память?!
            // А новую выделять кто будет - Дейкстра?
            arr = (unsigned char *)malloc(rhs.size*sizeof(unsigned char));

            memcpy(this->arr, rhs.arr, rhs.size);
            this->size = rhs.size;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Test2& operator=(Test2&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            free(this->arr);
            this->arr = rhs.arr;
            this->size = rhs.size;
            rhs.arr = nullptr;
            rhs.size = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test2 a(3); //1, 0, 1
    a.Set(0, 1);
    a.Set(2, 1);

    //Test2 b = a << 3;

    Test2 b(1);
    b = a << 3;
}
```

Немного о ваших исправлениях...

Было в старом совсем страшно:

```
Test2(Test2&& x) noexcept {
    free(this->arr);   // Что вы удаляете? Эта память не выделялась!
    this->size = x.size;  
    this->arr = x.arr;  // Теперь у вас два указателя указывают на одну память
                        // и два деструктора будут ее пытаться дважды освободить
```

В операторе `<<` вы просто обеспечивали себе утечку памяти...

Да, тут

```
Test2 b = a << 3;
```

вызывается конструктор копирования, а тут - обычный конструктор

```
Test2 b(1);
```

и присвоение

```
b = a << 3;
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Я на си учился, к плюсам не особо привык еще, делаю класс битового массива с автоматическим изменением размера и без ограничений. В std все медленное, vector, bitset, string, все в разы медленнее аналогов самописных, да и самому интересно разобраться во всем)

Comment: Интересно... Давайте ваши самописные аналоги, и давайте сравним их  по скорости с "в разы более медленными" строками и векторами. Готовы к такому тестированию?

Comment: Давайте продолжим в вк или еще где-нибудь?

Comment: Зачем же? Здесь это будет интересно и поучительно для многих читателей сайта. Не говорю - прямо сегодня, все же Новый год на носу, но как только - пишите, будем сравнивать..

Comment: Ну так что? Новый год прошел, вернемся к дискуссии о том, насколько в С++ все медленное? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test2 {
private:
    unsigned char* arr;
    size_t size;
public:
    ~Test2() {
        free(this->arr);
        this->size = 0;
    }
    Test2(size_t size) {
        this->size = size;
        this->arr = (unsigned char*)calloc(size, sizeof(this->arr));
    }
    Test2(Test2 const& copy) : size(copy.size), arr(new unsigned char[copy.size]){
        memcpy(this->arr, copy.arr, copy.size);
    }
    Test2(Test2&& x) noexcept {
        this->size = x.size;
        this->arr = x.arr;
        x.arr = nullptr;
        x.size = 0;
    }
    void Resize(size_t newsize) {
        this->arr = (unsigned char*)realloc(this->arr, newsize);
        for (size_t i = this->size; i < newsize; i++) {
            this->arr[i] = 0;
        }
        this->size = newsize;
    }
    void Set(size_t index, unsigned char value) {
        if (index < size) {
            this->arr[index] = value;
        }
        else {
            throw new exception("Out of bounds of an array");
        }
    }
    Test2 operator<<(size_t N) {
        Test2 c(this->size + N);
        for (size_t i = N; i < this->size + N; i++) {
            c.Set(i, this->arr[i - N]);
        }
        return c;
    }
    Test2& operator=(const Test2& rhs) {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            free(this->arr);
            memcpy(this->arr, rhs.arr, rhs.size);
            this->size = rhs.size;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    Test2& operator=(Test2&& rhs) noexcept {
        if (this != &rhs) {
            free(this->arr);
            this->arr = rhs.arr;
            this->size = rhs.size;
            rhs.arr = nullptr;
            rhs.size = 0;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test2 a(3); //1, 0, 1
    a.Set(0, 1);
    a.Set(2, 1);

    //Test2 b = a << 3;

    Test2 b(1);
    b = a << 3;
}
```

Такой вариант работает, теперь временная переменная удаляется после вызова конструктора перемещения. Вот только я не понял почему до этого через стек вызывало деструктор до перемещения.